# Crashed: com.apple.root.utility-qos

Tags: ios, crash

Facing this strange issue where my app crashes after certain period of time. Attached is the screenshot from the Crashlytics as well.

This has occurred in an iPhone 6Plus running iOS 11.4.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see a full crash log to get more information. With anything related to concurrency, I like to take a look at what all the threads are doing. Sometimes there is a clue in a thread that did not crash.

I do not know what's going on. But I can make an educated guess here that you are seeing heap corruption of some kind. The function "os_unfair_lock_corruption_abort" strongly indicates that the OS's primitive locking mechanism has detected a corrupted data structure, and is killing the processing.

Heap corruption is super-common, and can be extremely difficult to debug. One of the reasons is what you are seeing here is a symptom of the corruption, not the source. The source could be completely unrelated to locking/OperationQueue internals.

My suggestions would be to try out the memory debugging tools at your disposal, and attempt to fix all issues you can find. You might never be able to know which, if any, cause this. But, that's pretty much all you can do.

Check out malloc scribble, guardmalloc, and even NSZombies. All could potentially turn up some heap corruption bugs that are in your code.